# Binding event handler to any possible event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know i can bind event handler to multiple events, but is it possible to fire event handler for all events regardless of event type that occurs on specific element?

i meant something like this:

```
  $("#myElement").bind(function(){

  //this will fire on any event
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery you can get the events attached to an element by calling:

```
$._data(element, 'events')
```

With that information you could manually fire each in turn, although you may have to be careful with what parameters you pass in.

Comment: Oh, and this might not be supported so you may have issues with later jQuery versions.